# ciclo de paginacion automatico de TABLA con PHP y jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo una tabla ya paginada, y necesito un ciclo que esté mostrando los registros cada determinado tiempo por eso el `setTimeout` en mi caso la variable $b es la que se encarga de crear los botones que contienen el href dependiendo los registros se van creando más botones, al presionar uno de estos se pasa el valor a la variable "page".

Éste es el código que crea los botones

```
for($b=1; $b<=$a; $b++)
{
    ?><a href="paging.php?page=<?php echo $b;?>">
<?php echo $b." ";?> </a> <?php
}
```

Este es mi codigo de javascript

```
setTimeout(function(){
<?php
$b=1;
?>

   location.href="paging.php?page=<?php echo $b?>"

 <?php $B++?>
    } , 2000); 
</script>
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Parece que hay cierta confusión entre lo que es PHP y lo que es JavaScript. Deberías separarlos mejor y tener en cuenta que los valores de PHP no estarán disponibles en JS (al menos no después de que se cargue la página). Aparte de eso, debes tener cuidado porque tanto PHP como JavaScript son _case sensitive_, es decir, diferencian entre mayúsculas y minúsculas (no es lo mismo `$b` y `$B`)

Comment: ok muchas gracias por tu comentario @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que la página cambie cada 2 segundos?

Comment: exacto, que se este incrementando mi variable de $b y cuando llegue al limite de los botones, en mi caso ahorita son 3 , porque pagina por cada 10 registros y tengo en total 22 registros esto hace que la pagina 3 muestre solo 2 registros en la tabla y comienze desde el principio @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: y `$a` contiene el número total de páginas, ¿correcto?

Comment: $numero = mysqli_num_rows($registros1);
$a=($numero/10);
correcto, toma el total y los divide entre los registros que quiero que muestre. @AlvaroMontoro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que hay cierta confusión entre lo que es PHP y lo que es JavaScript en el código. Deberías separarlos mejor y tener en cuenta que los valores de PHP no estarán disponibles en JS (al menos no después de que se cargue la página).

Aparte de eso, debes tener cuidado porque tanto PHP como JavaScript son case sensitive, es decir, diferencian entre mayúsculas y minúsculas (no es lo mismo $b y $B).

El código PHP que genera los enlaces está bien. Lo único que tienes que hacer es cambiar el código JavaScript para que la página se actualice cada 2 segundos. Para ello sólo requieres pocos cambios:

- Comprueba que la página es correcta
- Calcula el próximo valor (en PHP)
- Pasa ese valor a JavaScript (cuando se crea la página)

El código podría ser algo como esto:

```
<?php
   // si hay un parámetro page que es numérico y page+1 sigue siendo una página válida
   if (isset($_GET["page"]) && is_numeric($_GET["page"]) && $_GET["page"]+1 <= $a) {
       // entonces, la próxima página será page+1
       $proxima = $_GET["page"] + 1;
   } else {
       // si no, la siguiente página será la primera
       $proxima = 1;
   }
?>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
   var b = <?php echo $proxima; ?>;
   location.href = "paging.php?page=" + b;
} , 2000); 
</script>
```

Comment: WOW! Me ha funcionado, llevaba demasiado tiempo tratando de resolverlo, Muchisimas gracias amigo :D @Alvaro Montoro